Intelephense not detecting type: Expected type 'object'. Found 'unset'.intelephense(P1006)
I'm using VSCode 1.90.2 and PHP Intelephense v1.11.2.
I'm working on a site where each PHP page requires a init.php. In this init script other required scripts are loaded, incl. one to connect to a database.
E.g. the requested page is login.php.
At the start it says
require 'include/init.php';

In init.php some configuration is loaded and finally the script db_connect.php:
require  'include/db_connect.php';

In db_connect.php a new PDO instance is created.
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db_host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db_db'] . ';charset=utf8mb4', $config['db_user'], $config['db_pass']);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


So far, so good. The code works.
Now Intelephense complains in login.php that $dbh is unset.
Expected type 'object'. Found 'unset'.intelephense(P1006)
@var unset $dbh

It looks like Intelephense 'forgets' what happens in the deeper nested required files.
Things I tried:

Move the code from db_connect.php to init.php. That works, but it"s not what I want.
Add global $dbh; after the require instruction in login.php. This works too, but that's something I would have to add to every script, which is also not what I want and the reason I use a init script in the first place.
I also don't understand why a global fixes this. $dbh should be in the same scope and available. Since the code works without it.
If I copy or clone the instance of $dbh in init.php there is no error anymore, but the type of $dbh changes from \PDO to mixed. The result is that code completion stops working.

Question: Is this a quirk of Intelephense or something that can be influenced with the settings? Or am I missing something regarding PHP?
Is there a way to have this working with just the one require statement and no complaining from Intelephense?
EDIT: I found out that this is caused by the pre-release version of Intelephense. Since I code on an offline PC I downloaded the extension from the first hit on Google, the marketplace https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client. Here the version is 1.11.5 with zero mention that it is a pre-release version.
I noticed that when I copied the code to an online PC and downloaded the extension in VSCode itself. Then the version is 1.10.4 and the issue doesn't exist.
With the release version there is no code error, but it still doesn't recognize the type of $dbh, so no code completion. I guess I can live with that for now.

If you opt for a workaround, tell the linter about your global variables by using annotations: /** @var \PDO $dbh */. (I don't know whether Intelephense follows includes, I haven't used it for quite a while).

That's also something I tried and it works, but it's another solution that requires additional text on the script that uses the init script.
But I found out that it might be due to the pre-release version of intelephense. I'm going to edit the original post.

I've had the to chance to test this and it seems that Intelephense does follow includes but it won't track variables in more than one level. So your options are: 1) Reduce nested includes. 2) Find another IDE (PhpStorm handles this, though it's paid software). 3) Redesign application. 4) Resort to workarounds.
